# Cucumber Gherkin how to add ordinal numbers

Tags: bdd, gherkin

i am finding aswer how to be able to write into Gherkin Cucumber BDD ordinal numbers...

For example i have:

When('I add something into {int} block',..)

I know i can write:
When('I add something into {int} (st/nd/rd) block',..)

But is there another way?

Comment: That is the way to do it. I've implemented similar step definitions. I haven't found a cleaner way.

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you are wanting another way?

Comment: bsc i am to lazy write in every custom BDD (st/nd/rd/th) ... but it is looks like that´s the way i have to go :(

Comment: so i used it like upper When('I add something into {int}(st/nd/rd) block',..) but i get error from cypress: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Parameter types cannot be alternative: